# microsoft.service.hub error after installing Visual Studio Community edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After re-installing Visual Studio Community edition I've been getting this error.

[image]

I get the error right after the splashscreen shows

Answer (score 2):

> Could not load file or assembly '**Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client**'

Please open File Explorer and search this file name to verify this file is existing on your computer or not.

Meanwhile, you can have a try with the following to troubleshoot this issue:

- Clear all folders and files under the folder: `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx\` and restart the VS 2017 to check it again.
- Open `cmd` and navigate to the VS 2017 installation folder like `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\xxx\Common7\IDE` and run the command: `devenv /safemode` to run it as safe mode, then check if the installed extensions caused this issue.
- Re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and choose **Repair** to repair it